# Python inconsistent error when comparing two very large numbers

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and I'm writing a secure ftp server/client to handle basic uploading/downloading of files (but encrypted).

To ensure the client has the secret key, I encrypt and send a randomized 32 byte number. The client must decrypt the number, add one, re-encrypt it, and return it to the server. The server checks to see that the response is the random number + 1, then proceeds with the connection in the case that they are equivalent. The issue is that this works like 90% of the time, but sometimes will fail (even when the client sends a good response).

```
if int.from_bytes(challenge, "big") + 1 == int.from_bytes(response, "big"):
    print("Good\nExpected: {0}\nReceived: {0}".format(
        int.from_bytes(challenge, "big") + 1,
        int.from_bytes(response, "big")))
else: 
    print("Bad\nExpected: {0}\nReceived: {0}".format(
        int.from_bytes(challenge, "big") + 1,
        int.from_bytes(response, "big")))
```

9 times out of 10, this enters the True condition, however sometimes it fails. These are the examples of when it has failed:

```
Bad
Expected:
65159048323870645118410560973513118036375130115063959378348917255680432299875
Received: 
65159048323870645118410560973513118036375130115063959378348917255680432299875

Bad
Expected:
94602782648778784750235610259612519850690550920952731294858863927077528757933
Received:
94602782648778784750235610259612519850690550920952731294858863927077528757933
```

Note that every one of the above expected and received are actually identical.

Here are some examples of numbers that *succeeded*:

```
Good
Expected:
91751260209520864629218443027060768890746721638897648279482154562044918570881
Received:
91751260209520864629218443027060768890746721638897648279482154562044918570881

Good
Expected: 
104504930179798203375748204555227260444250367405369759767776407892919812999121
Received:
104504930179798203375748204555227260444250367405369759767776407892919812999121
```

Any idea what's going on? Thanks for your time.
Edit: Code snippet:

Server side:

```
challenge = os.urandom(32)
socket.send_msg(challenge, encrypt=True)
response = socket.recv_msg(32, decrypt=True)

if int.from_bytes(challenge, "big") + 1 != int.from_bytes(response, "big"):
    print("Expected: {0}\nReceived: {0}".format(int.from_bytes(challenge, "big") + 1, int.from_bytes(response, "big")))
```

client side:

```
challenge = self._socket.recv_raw(32, decrypt=True)
challenge = int.from_bytes(challenge, "big") + 1
self.sckt.send_msg(challenge.to_bytes(32, "big"), encrypt=True)
```

Note that I have thoroughly tested the encryption code and socket messaging protocol, those are not the issue.

Comment: Please provide a minimal code sample so we can run it and see the error.

Comment: Your condition looks backwards? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is this really the code you're using? This outputs `Good` if the numbers are _different_.

Comment: @Rawing sorry the code is not identical, the outputs are reversed. I'll add a code snippet...

Comment: In the first snippet, please change `!=` to `==`.

Comment: @Denziloe The code is being encrypted with aes128 then decrypted, I cannot provide enough code for you to be able to run this as my company will not allow it. However, those outputs should be enough should they not? It's comparing two really big numbers, and failing when they are equal. I normally work with lower level languages where numbers of this size would have to be inspected element by element rather than directly, so I wasn't sure if I was just misusing the python '==' on large numbers.

Comment: No those outputs are not enough, if I paste them into my interpreter it works fine. That is not the issue. You certainly can provide enough code. Nobody wants your entire script, we just want inputs to the script you gave that will cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: Could you post the output of `print((challenge, response))`?

Comment: @Rawing interesting, when I print out the raw byte contents, it prints this: (b'\x95\xb1\x19kH+O\x01\xa2T\xc9Y\xde\x06\x1b\x01\xa3O\xad\\\x1a\xbc\x9bfy\xf2\xbc,\xda\xc8\xac\x86', b''), but when I later convert the "response" to a number, it prints out the large number....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is with your `format` calls. You're using `{0}` twice, which means you get the first positional argument repeated twice in the output text. The integer conversion of `response` is never printed.

To fix the reporting (not whatever issue is causing the mismatched data), you should either use `{0}` and `{1}` once each, or leave out the numbers completely (Python will automatically use `{0}` for the first `{}` and `{1}` for the second, etc.

Comment: This was absolutely the problem. The byte array I was receiving was empty due to a bad padding algorithm and the noob that I am didn't look well enough into a "tested" function. Thank you very much.